# Usage of conform

Tags: questions

I am trying to make a sentence that means the same as "dont be satisfied with what you do now" but I want to use "conform" instead like in "Dont be conformed with what you do".

Is this the correct way to do it? OR maybe "contented" will suit better?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!!! **conform** has completely different meaning. It can't be used to mean the same as **satisfied**. I'm sure you already know it and you want to ask something else. Please edit your question so that it's easy for people to understand better what you want to know :-)

Comment: Then what about "dont be CONTENTED with what you do"

Comment: hmmm it can be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to say **conformed**, you could say something like this:

> Don't conform to your current way of doing things.

**Conform** in this context means to fit within given parameters, or to follow a precedent.

That might not be quite what you want to say. You suggested **contented**, and that word could work very naturally, like either of these sentences:

> Don't be content with your current way of doing things.
>
> Don't be contented with your current way of doing things.

The word **content** (with the stress on the second syllable) means thinking or feeling that all your needs are satisfied. "Don't be content with *X*" suggests that being content with *X* would be lazy or fail to achieve the best you can.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought. But is there any way to say that without the "be"? Like using another verb. Or better yet, if a similar phrase already exists in the popular culture I would rather use that.

Comment: "Don't be content with" is a well-known and very clear phrase, which carries the connotation described above. If you really wanted to avoid "be", you could say "Don't content yourself with" or "Don't settle for" or "Don't accept", but I don't think these phrases are as clear or strong as "Don't be content with".